# View image metadata in Whatsapp

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, metadata, whatsapp

Is there a way to see an image's metadata from a file that was sent using Whatsapp. My cousin recieved a photo that i sent to a group few days ago,  and he don't want to tell me who sent it back to him, is there a way see who re-send the photo i sent on the group to him? I've been reading about metadata apps similar to exifool, i've also heared that Linux has a command to do similar tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Do-pictures-sent-on-WhatsApp-keep-their-EXIF-data), as well as other sources on the net, Whatsapp strips away all metadata from any image.  This is common among most social media sites/apps.